How to merge at intersection line point?
i want to merge at intersection line point , how can i do ?


If these are edges at the same height (co-planar), in Options check Auto Merge and Split Edges & Faces.
Select a point and press  e to extrude it over the other, or grab and drag the edge until the intersection point. At the intersection point, there will be a new vertex.

A useful free extension on the Blender website is TinyCAD. It has a command called 'XALL' that will take all existing overlapping edges and create vertices at the intersections.

related: Can I automatically extend lines from SVG?
